# How to share protected credentials with team members?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, figaro-ruby

If you use [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) in your Rails app to ensure private credentials never get pushed source control how do you share that information with team members? For example, if I bring in a new team member tomorrow she won't be able to start developing without me manually sharing my `application.yml` file (we're using Figaro). I'm new to this and just trying to understand best practices.

Comment: Post them to a work chat or something. If you're worried about security, use encrypted chat with auto-destructing messages. :)

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev - I was hoping that there would be something a little more robust but that makes sense.

Comment: If you're looking for some automation, you can have a chat bot that sends this stuff to all new members of the room.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is "good enough" (even without the bot) and doesn't require any setup. Unless you're onboarding 300 people per day. In which case you'll need the bot.